# Ionic FAB: Chrome Display Issue

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 and I have some [FAB Buttons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabButton/) in use that appear over the header (`top edge`).  Very recently these stopped appearing above the header and now appear under it.  The symptom can be seen in the [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabContainer/) when viewing their demos.

Anyone else seeing this issue?  Did Chrome make a change that adjusted how Z-Index is handled?  For reference, FAB's still look good in FireFox and iOS/Safari.

**Update after more research**

- This seems to have started with Chrome 71
- An [Ionic Forums post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-fabs-ion-fab-under-header-since-chrome-71/150188) has some additional detail
- A [Github Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16780) has been submitted to the Ionic team

While there are some work-arounds, it seems like there isn't a solid explanation (and thus no solid long-term fix).

Comment: I hacked together a silly example from hunting and pecking the hundreds of styles in an Ionic app that shows the problem a little clearer.  This example has a fake FAB that appears normally in FireFox but not in Chrome 71.  https://js-bjvaxt.stackblitz.io/

Comment: As noted in the Github issue, this seems to boil down to a difference in how Chrome 71 handles the `contain: layout size style;` style on `ion-content`.  Removing that style bumps the FAB on top again like it used to be (and like FF has it).  Not sure if this is a bug in Chrome 71 or intentional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16780) on this, I resolved this in my app by putting the following CSS in the ionic app.scss:

```
ion-content {
  contain: size style;
}
```

This will basically take the `contain: layout` style out of the mix, which is causing the problem.  FireFox/Safari don't implement `contain:layout` yet ([see here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918889)), which is why the FABs work there.  Eventually those will break too unless a change like this is added.